# docker-entrypoint executing a jboss with gracefully shutdown

Tags: docker, jboss

I have a docker-entrypoint.sh file that execute a standalone.sh from jboss-eap-7, see:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
sh $JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.sh -DANTLR_USE_DIRECT_CLASS_LOADING=true
exec "$@"
```

This works very well, but running `ps -eaf` in my container i got this process list:

```
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 jboss     0:00 {docker-entrypoi} /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
    8 jboss     0:00 sh /home/jboss/jboss-eap-7.1/bin/standalone.sh -DANTLR_USE_DIRECT_CLASS_LOADING=true
   66 jboss     1:22 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/bin/java -D[Standalone] -server -verbose:gc -Xloggc:/home/jboss/jboss-eap-7.1/standalone/log/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=3M -XX:-TraceClassUnloading -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0 -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/home/jboss/jboss-eap-7.1/standalone/log/server.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:/home/jboss/jboss-eap-7.1/standalone/configuration/logging.properties -jar /home/jboss/jboss-eap-7.1/jboss-modules.jar -mp /home/jboss/jboss-eap-7.1/modules org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=/home/jboss/jboss-eap-7.1 -Djboss.server.base.dir=/home/jboss/jboss-eap-7.1/standalone -DANTLR_USE_DIRECT_CLASS_LOADING=true
  293 jboss     0:00 ps -eaf
```

Look, the standalone.sh get the PID 8, so when i send a `docker stop` i got a 10s delay and a force kill, but i would like to send a gracefully shutdown.

Any tips to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

docker stop ----time=30 foo

(source: https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/gracefully-stopping-docker-containers/)